# Why apache adds .php to URI

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Noticed Apache strange behavior. 
I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect every

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*css|gif|js|png$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

So when i type 
    www.example.com/something

in browser, inside index.php $_REQUEST['q'] returns 'something'

But besides index.php there are some other php files in root folder (profile.php, for example).

So when i type

```
www.example.com/profile
```

inside index.php $_REQUEST['q'] returns 'profile.php'

Why does this .php appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) is enabled.  Try disabling it by adding:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

To your `.htaccess` file.